# Audio formats supported by DICOM

Tags: audio, dicom

What audio formats are supported by DICOM as per DICOM standards?

Answer (score 3):

[DICOM Supplement 30](ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/final/sup30_f2.pdf) added support for waveforms to the DICOM Standard.  Included in this is support for audio waveforms.

Also, there was the addition of support for MPEG2 video in [DICOM Supplement 42](ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/final/sup42_ft.pdf).  This video support allows encoding of mp3 data within the video stream.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, since the question is a little older:

Supplement 30 indeed added support for audio with the Basic Voice(!) Audio object. However, it only supports 8000 Hz sampling frequency.

Therefore later on DICOM introduced the General Audio Waveform object that permits up to 44,100 Hz.

Both objects are restricted to two audio channels,i.e. permit mono or stereo recordings. You can find information about them in part 3 of the DICOM standard.

Furthermore, DICOM also supports not only MPEG2 but also MPEG4 video. Look into DICOM part 5 for further information.

Michael